# Sylius V0.17 How to add payment methods

Tags: payment, gateway, sylius, omnipay

I installed Sylius via `composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard acme` on my local server to take a closer look at it for a upcoming project. Now I'm stuck at adding payment-methods/ a payment-gateway.

I tried to follow the [docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusOmnipayBundle/installation.html) and install omnipay-bundle but `composer require "sylius/omnipay-bundle"` failed with:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for sylius/omnipay-bundle ^0.9.0 -> satisfiable by sylius/omnipay-bundle[v0.9.0].
    - Conclusion: remove omnipay/omnipay 2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install omnipay/omnipay 2.3.2
    - sylius/omnipay-bundle v0.9.0 requires omnipay/omnipay 1.0.* -> satisfiable by omnipay/omnipay[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: omnipay/omnipay[v1.0.0, 2.3.2].
    - Can only install one of: omnipay/omnipay[v1.0.1, 2.3.2].
    - Can only install one of: omnipay/omnipay[v1.0.2, 2.3.2].
    - Can only install one of: omnipay/omnipay[v1.0.3, 2.3.2].
    - Can only install one of: omnipay/omnipay[v1.0.4, 2.3.2].
    - Installation request for omnipay/omnipay == 2.3.2.0 -> satisfiable by omnipay/omnipay[2.3.2].
```

Adding the bundle to the appkernel.php anyway and/or adding configuration to config.yml (like described in the docs) prevents the Server from starting.

I found this issue: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/4396
which seems related.

Question: 
- Should there be some choices other than 'Offline' in 'Payment Methods' in the Admin-Frontend (without adding code to the freshly-pulled sylius)?
- Is Sylius changing so rapidly that the docs are not matching?
- Lets assume I want to add '2checkout' (just as exampl) as payment gateway, what would i have to do?

I have the feeling i missed something fundamental with this problem :)
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: omnipay/1.x has been deprecated for a long time. There must be a later version of the sylius omnipay bundle or sylius itself that supports omnipay 2.x. Probably best raise an issue with the sylius devs to ask what you should be doing there.

Comment: Digging a bit further it seems that sylius/omnipay-bundle is obsolete -- more than 2 years old. sylius itself has omnipay integration directly in the main project which appears to be up to date.  To add payment methods you probably just need to require the appropriate gateway, e.g. composer require omnipay/paypal

Comment: Thank you for your Answer!
`composer require omnipay/paypal` failed while clearing a cache, while
`composer require omnipay/2checkout` succeeded while rendering a `An Exception was thrown while handling: Internal Server Error`. The Log says:
`"Attempted to call an undefined method named "setResourceOwnerMap" of class "HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\OAuthUtils"`
After fixing that in the appropriate file I required (just for testing):
omnipay/omnipay
omnipay/stripe
payum/payum
payum/stripe

But still no sign of any other payment-method other than offline. I'm keeping digging...

Answer (score 3):

My Question was answered in the Git-issue [4369](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/4396)

So, the sylius-standard already contains the Symfony2-Bundles.
To add a payment-gateway they just need to be configured in config.yml:

```
payum:
    gateways:
        paypal_express_checkout:
            paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
                username:  %paypal.express_checkout.username%
                password:  %paypal.express_checkout.password%
                signature: %paypal.express_checkout.signature%
                sandbox:   %paypal.express_checkout.sandbox%
        klarna_checkout:
            klarna_checkout:
                secret:  'required'
                merchant_id: 'required'
                sandbox: true
sylius_payment:
    gateways:
        paypal_express_checkout: Paypal Express Checkout
        klarna_checkout: Klarna Checkout
```

Additional configuration reference can be found here:
https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.md

Thanks!

PS: The cache has to be cleared before restarting the server.